# steps to integrate coverity SA with visual studio 2005 and how to run the same?

Tags: c++, static-analysis

I am unable find good documentation on steps to integrate coverity SA tool with VS 2005 and then run SA on the code....
  Please let me know if you have any info regrading the same
Thanks
GaneshK

Answer (score 2):

Coverity SA tool has a plug-in for Visual Studio.

You can download it from your Coverity Integrity Manager aka Coverity Platform.

Go to yourcimurl:8080/extras/index.html (if you are on the latest version 6.x).

That's also where you can find documentation for it.